# Generating chart in excel with jxls for collection of unknown size

Tags: excel, charts, jxls

On this homepage http://jxls.sourceforge.net/samples/chartsample.html is described how a chart can be generated with jxls.
But in this example the size of the collection is known.
How can I do it if I don't know the size?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this through the use of named range in excel.

In your template.xls define a named range that spans through the whole foreach tag. Please see the image below.

[image: Excel Template File]

The resulting names after template processing will be the range of the whole collection. in my case its up to row 39 shown below

[image: Excel Result File]

To display the chart dynamically, create the chart in your template file and set the data source to be *='SheetName'!RangeName*. This will create the chart in the output file dynamically

For more cleaner approach http://amateuratbest.blogspot.com.au/2007/08/excel-charting-in-java.html has information on using the OFFSET function in excel, but it was too hard for my simple task.